# Complexity of a recursive function c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, complexity-theory

*I'm trying to calculate the complexity Big-Theta-Notation of the following function:
variable i is constant == 3
*

```
void g(int i, int n) {
    if (i>0) {
        for (int j=n+10; j>0; j-=5) {
            g(i-2, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Because it's a recursive function, I thought I should calculate it with Master Theorem, but actually there is no division of n. I would be very greatful for any kind of help!

Comment: It's not necessarily recursive.  The function `g()` you show takes one argument and calls another (overloaded) `g()` that takes two arguments.   Unless the two-argument `g()` calls the one-argument `g()`, there is no recursion going on.   And since you haven't described the two-argument `g()`, there is no way to estimate the complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relation is T(i, n) = (n+10)T(i-2, n)/5.

The terms for both odd and even `i` are geometric progressions with the multiplication factor (n+10)/5. This solves to T(i, n) = O((n/5)^(i/2)), or O(sqrt(n/5)^i) if you prefer.